# Deleting from a dynamically allocated array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation

So I have a 2D array

```
char **m_data
```

This array has a width of `width` and the height is given by a vector called `m_heigths`.

```
// Remove blank space where necessary
// Iterate through every row
for (int x=0; x<m_width; ++x){
// count number of spaces
    int spaces=0;
    // iterate through the given row
    for (int y=0; y<m_heigths[x]; ++y){
    // if space is occupied by a black space increment count
        if (m_data[x][y]==' '){
            ++spaces;
        }
    }
    // check if entire column is just a bunch of blanks
    if (spaces==m_heigths[x]){
        // get rid of blanks
        delete [] m_data[x];
    }
}
```

So I want to look for a column that is just a bunch of blank spaces and delete it. but this does not seemed to work, the blank spaces stay there. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please elaborate what does "does not seemed to work" mean.

Comment: By delete do you mean "remove the row from the array"?

Comment: Have you looked into a collection like a `vector` which can allow you to do this very easily? Otherwise you are going to have a very hard time on your hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete` only releases the allocated memory. To truely delete the row you'll need to copy (in this case, just copy the pointers) all rows below up by one after you call delete. Like Hayden said in the comments it'll probably be easier to use an STL container.